# Does Kafka broker store metadata?

Tags: apache-kafka

Does Kafka broker store metadata which producer API uses (e.g. which partitions are leader for a topic etc.)? As per my understanding this metadata is stored in Zookeeper , is it correct? If it is true then how Brokers are updated by Zookeeper with latest information?

Answer (score 6):

All Kafka brokers can answer a metadata request that describes the current state of the cluster: what topics there are, which partitions those topics have, which broker is the leader for those partitions etc.

ZooKeeper is responsible for:

- Electing a controller broker - and making sure there is only one
- Cluster membership - allowing brokers to join a cluster
- Topic configuration - which topics exist, how many partitions each has, where are the replicas, who is the preferred leader, what configuration overrides are set for each topic
- Quotas - how much data is each client allowed to read and write
- ACLs - who is allowed to read and write to which topic

There is regular communication between Kafka and ZooKeeper such that ZooKeeper knows a Kafka broker is still alive (ZooKeeper heartbeat mechanism) and also in response to events such as a topic being created or a replica falling out of sync for a topic-partition.

Comment: Why the -1? My sources:
- [All brokers can answer metadata request](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_loadbalancing)
- [ZooKeeper responsibilities as answered by Kafka committer and Confluent employee (see comments)](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-actual-role-of-Zookeeper-in-Kafka-What-benefits-will-I-miss-out-on-if-I-don%E2%80%99t-use-Zookeeper-and-Kafka-together)

Answer (score 4):

Kafka is a distributed system and is built to use Zookeeper which is responsible for controller election, topic configuration, clustering etc.

More precisely, Zookeeper initiates controller election. The controller broker is a single broker in the Kafka cluster which takes care of leader broker and followers for every partition. When a particular broker is taken down, the controller lets other replicas know (in order to handle partition leaders etc). Moreover, when the controller fails then Zookeeper initiates new elections in order to elect the new broker which will act as the controller.

Furthermore, Zookeeper knows which brokers are part of the Kafka cluster and which are still alive. Similarly, it is also aware of topic-specific information such as which topics exist, how many partitions each has, where are the replicas and so on.

Zookeeper also stores information regarding quotas and ACLs, i.e. what volume of data each client is allowed to consume/produce and also, who is allowed to consume or produce from a particular topic.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I still have this question - why producers make metadata request to bootstrap brokers if zookeeper keeps all metadata

Comment: well, you should think that what clients take care about are the Kafka brokers. They have to exchange messages through them ... so they don't care about Zookeeper. For example, in older versions the consumers committed their offsets to Zookeeper but this dependency was removed so that now a Kafka topic is used for that. Clients should not know about Zookeeper which is used behind the scenes by the brokers for what is described above.

Comment: Kafka clients connects to the bootstrap server which can be any broker in the cluster. The broker then retrieves the metadata information from the zookeeper. This design provide flexibility and removes dependency of the client on the zookeeper